# BluetoothLEDevice in Nuget package consumed by WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-desktop

I'm attempting to build a NuGet package that can be consumed by WPF applications that utilize the Windows libraries that contain `BluetoothLEDevice` and related classes.  Existing applications that need this functionality are WPF applications and I don't quite understand what the limitations are around this.  Currently, some things work while others do not.

For instance, I get a `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Windows Runtime (WinRT) is not supported on this platform.'` error when I use the device watcher to obtain a reference to the device I'm looking to connect to and then call `DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(...)`.

- What should my NuGet package be targeting in terms of framework/standard version?
- What do the existing WPF applications have to target to be able to consume this?

I've tried setting the `TargetPlatformVersion` to 10 for the WPF app.  I also see different results depending on whether I reference my class library in the solution from a WPF project vs. loading it in as a NuGet package.

I'm having trouble finding recent documentation on this.

Comment: Later?  Or earlier?  I'd be surprised if a 4.5.1 WPF application could consume a 4.7.2 NuGet package.  But if that's the case, that's cool!

Comment: Instead, what I've tried is WPF targeting 4.7.2 and the nuget package targets 4.6.  But I still get this error

Comment: How is WinRT related to your question? Are you the author of the NuGet package?

Comment: @mm8 `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` and `windows.winmd` are required references to use the Windows 10 APIs that include Bluetooth Low Energy libraries.